# Unable to move a file from one My Drive root to another My Drive root

Tags: google-drive-api

Here's the scenario:

- User1 with file test.txt in My Drive root (i.e., test.txt does not exist inside a folder in User1's My Drive and is instead at the top level).
- User2 with no files or folders in My Drive.
- The test.txt file is shared with User2 (Editor access).

Goal: Move the file from the root of User1's My Drive to the root of User2's My Drive.

If I retrieve the test.txt file using files.list() and as User2, I get the following (trimmed) list of fields:

```
{
  "kind": "drive#file",
  "id": "REDACTED",
  "name": "fixtest2.txt",
  "shared": true,
  "ownedByMe": false,
  "capabilities": {
      "canMoveItemWithinDrive": true,
  },
}
```

According to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/multi-parenting#move_a_file_to_another_parent_folder), I should be able to call files.update() as User2 to remove the existing parent ID and add the new one because canMoveItemWithinDrive is true. This doesn't work, however, and results in an HTTP 404 because User2 does not have access to User1's My Drive root ID (the existing parent ID I want to remove).

This process works fine for any file that is in a folder within User1's My Drive and for which User2 has been granted Editor access at the folder level. But since you cannot grant access to the My Drive root, it fails for any files that are at the top level.

Is this a documentation bug, a functional bug, both, or neither? It seems like it is at least a documentation bug because the current wording simply does not work in this scenario. I would argue that if it's not a functional bug, it is at least a major hole that should be corrected. If I can move files that are in folders, I should be able to move files that are not in folders, too.

Comment: My bet is working as intended but pop it up on the issue forum and see what google says https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:191650%2B.   There are a lot of things you cant do with the root dir, you cant share your root dir with another user for example.

Comment: Hi ! Could you please share how you are creating the file in the first place and then the update request you are running without providing any sensitive information? Is the file object you shared the one you obtain from your User 2 when you run ```files.list()```? Also, when you request ```GET``` on your file does it return any ```parents``` field? Have you tried copying the file and then moving the copy to the root directory rather than trying to move the shared file?